# how to reference myClass in MSBuild tag <PropertyGroup>

Tags: c#, msbuild

this is my .csproj file and I want to use the custom class to build the version number I need.

for example:

```
<PropertyGroup>
<TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
<CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>false</CopyRefAssembliesToPublishDirectory>
<Deterministic>false</Deterministic>
<GenerateAssemblyInfo>true</GenerateAssemblyInfo>
 <myver>$([myClass]::get_myVersion())</myver>
  <Version>$(myver)</Version>
</PropertyGroup>
<ItemGroup>
<Reference Include="myClass">
  <HintPath>..\lib\myClass.dll</HintPath>
</Reference>
</ItemGroup>
......
```

how can I reference myClass to `PropertyGroup`?

Comment: Did you try using .net custom attribute similar to `System.Reflection.AssemblyVersionAttribute` ? AS the latter is a sealed class, create your own so that you can choose what to do in the `Version` property. The class should be in a common assembly you can reference in any project. The class must have, above its definition, the attribute `[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Assembly, Inherited = false)]`.

Comment: I don't think you can put some C# code in the CSPROJ file. So using the attribute decoration might be a better solution.

Comment: I think AssemblyVersionAttribute is deprecated by the <version> tag.

Answer (score 0):

[Property functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/property-functions?view=vs-2022) are supported for a fixed set of known types. You cannot use your own custom type. Custom types are not supported. You can't call the `myVersion` property getter on your `myClass` type as a property function.

You can write a custom MSBuild task and invoke your task from within a target. Tasks can be written inline. See "[MSBuild inline tasks with RoslynCodeTaskFactory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/msbuild/msbuild-roslyncodetaskfactory?view=vs-2022)".

A note on [Assembly attribute properties](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/project-sdk/msbuild-props#assembly-attribute-properties): The `$(Version)` property, if set, may be used to set the values of the `$(AssemblyVersion)` and `$(FileVersion)` properties.